# Extjs input file dialogue trigger event on dialogue close

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there anyway to capture the event when we select a file in open dialogue box and click ok button in extjs.
**off topic the field doesn't stretch from its normal width.

```
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'New (JPG or PNG only)',
        labelSeparator: '',
        name: 'newPic',
        id:'newPic',
        anchor:'100%',
        inputType: 'file',
        allowBlank: false,
```

When I ckick the browse button the open dialogue box opens. I need to capture the filename when I click the open button on the dialogue box.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/file-upload.html) from [ExtJS Examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/) page. It shows a working example of your scenario.